# Snap event does not get fired in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, snapping

I create a `snap` event as shown below in the code.
At run time, when I hover the mouse near by a vertex, the mouse pointer gets snapped/attached to that vertex but the `snap`event did not get fired.

Please let me know why the snap event does not get fired.

This is my code:

```
this.#snapEvt = this.#mapBuilderInstance.getSnapGeomForSource(this.#vectorSource);

getSnapGeomForSource(src) {
        return new Snap({ source: src });
    }

        this.#mapBuilderInstance.addInteractionEvtToMap(this.#mapInstance, this.#snapEvt);



this.#keyOnEvtSnap = this.#snapEvt.on('snap', evt => this.#evtListenerOnSnap(evt));
```

**add interaction to map**

```
addInteractionEvtToMap(map, evt) {
    if (map) {
        if (evt) {
            map.addInteraction(evt);
            return map;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any errors in the browser debugger console?

Comment: @TomazicM no, no errors. i also modified the pixelTolerancce as an attempt to solve it , but still does not work

Comment: But this piece of code looks a bit strange/uncomplete: `this.#mapInstance =`.

Comment: @TomazicM i modified it

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer why it does not work for you, but plain JS code below works OK for me:

```
function getSnapGeomForSource(src) {
  return new ol.interaction.Snap({source: src});
}

function addInteractionEvtToMap(map, evt) {
  if (map) {
    if (evt) {
      map.addInteraction(evt);
      return map;
    }
  }
}

function evtListenerOnSnap(evt) {
  console.log('snap', evt);
}

const snapEvt = getSnapGeomForSource(snapVectorSource);
addInteractionEvtToMap(map, snapEvt);
snapEvt.on('snap', evt => evtListenerOnSnap(evt));
```

Comment: @amr Was this of any help?