Cannot set a style to a feature in OpenLayers
As shown in the below posted code, I am trying to make a feature invisible to the user.
At run time, I receive the error posted below.
Why am I getting this error and how can I solve it?
code
this.#vectorSource.addFeature(this.#bufferedAsOLFeature.setStyle(new Style({
    fill: new Fill({
        color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)' // Transparent fill color
      }),
    stroke: new Stroke({
        color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)' // Transparent stroke color
      })
}))
            

error
util.js:28 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ol_uid')
at getUid (util.js:28:1)


What about answer to this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/479251/snap-event-does-not-get-fired-in-openlayers. It deserves at least some feedback.

@TomazicM i did not accept it because the issue still persists, i can not listen to snapping events

Then write this comment there.

@TomazicM wht should i write there??

What you wrote in your comment above.

If you look at the docs of .setStyle method, you'll see that it does not return any value, so you can't use it as input to .addFeature method.
You have to do it in two steps:
this.#bufferedAsOLFeature.setStyle(new Style({
  fill: new Fill({
    color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)' // Transparent fill color
  }),
  stroke: new Stroke({
    color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)' // Transparent stroke color
  })
});
this.#vectorSource.addFeature(this.#bufferedAsOLFeature);

